How to fix overlaying x axis in a plotly.js subplots?
I was trying to create a plot using plotly.js which have 2 subplots arranged in a grid with 8 tracks, 4 in each subplot. All track has separate y axis and shared x axis except one track which also have separate x axis. In some cases, my code is able to generate expected results. Here is how it looks:


var data = [{
    "x": [
      0,
      90,
      180,
      270
    ],
    "y": [
      148,
      67,
      54,
      729
    ],
    "type": "scatter",
    "yaxis": "y",
    "xaxis": "x",
    "name": "Channel Name 1",
    "showlegend": true,
    "visible": true,
    "marker": {
      "color": "rgba(76, 198, 233, 0.5)"
    },
    "line": {
      "width": 2,
      "color": "rgba(76, 198, 233, 0.5)"
    },
    "fillcolor": "rgba(76, 198, 233, 0.25)",
    "mode": "lines",
    "hoverinfo": "none"
  },
  {
    "x": [
      0,
      90,
      180,
      270
    ],
    "y": [
      649,
      34,
      0,
      128
    ],
    "type": "scatter",
    "yaxis": "y3",
    "xaxis": "x",
    "name": "Channel Name 2",
    "showlegend": true,
    "visible": true,
    "marker": {
      "color": "rgba(239, 151, 191, 0.5)"
    },
    "line": {
      "width": 2,
      "color": "rgba(239, 151, 191, 0.5)"
    },
    "fillcolor": "rgba(239, 151, 191, 0.25)",
    "mode": "lines",
    "hoverinfo": "none"
  },
  {
    "x": [
      0,
      90,
      180,
      270
    ],
    "y": [
      850,
      300,
      15,
      483
    ],
    "type": "scatter",
    "yaxis": "y5",
    "xaxis": "x",
    "name": "Channel Name 3",
    "showlegend": true,
    "visible": true,
    "marker": {
      "color": "rgba(245, 150, 50, 0.5)"
    },
    "line": {
      "width": 2,
      "color": "rgba(245, 150, 50, 0.5)"
    },
    "fillcolor": "rgba(245, 150, 50, 0.25)",
    "mode": "lines",
    "hoverinfo": "none"
  },
  {
    "x": [
      0,
      90,
      180,
      270
    ],
    "y": [
      0,
      374,
      585,
      16,
    ],
    "type": "scatter",
    "yaxis": "y7",
    "xaxis": "x",
    "name": "Channel Name 4",
    "showlegend": true,
    "visible": true,
    "marker": {
      "color": "rgba(218, 227, 109, 0.5)"
    },
    "line": {
      "width": 2,
      "color": "rgba(218, 227, 109, 0.5)"
    },
    "fillcolor": "rgba(218, 227, 109, 0.25)",
    "mode": "lines",
    "hoverinfo": "none"
  },
  {
    "x": [
      0,
      90,
      180,
      270,
    ],
    "y": [
      2,
      365,
      315,
      7,
    ],
    "type": "scatter",
    "yaxis": "y2",
    "xaxis": "x",
    "name": "Channel Name 5",
    "showlegend": true,
    "visible": true,
    "marker": {
      "color": "rgba(178, 74, 195, 0.5)"
    },
    "line": {
      "width": 2,
      "color": "rgba(178, 74, 195, 0.5)"
    },
    "fillcolor": "rgba(178, 74, 195, 0.25)",
    "mode": "lines",
    "hoverinfo": "none"
  },
  {
    "x": [
      0,
      90,
      180,
      270,
    ],
    "y": [
      0,
      294,
      639,
      346,
    ],
    "type": "scatter",
    "yaxis": "y4",
    "xaxis": "x2",
    "name": "Channel Name 6",
    "showlegend": true,
    "visible": true,
    "marker": {
      "color": "rgba(74, 211, 203, 0.5)"
    },
    "line": {
      "width": 2,
      "color": "rgba(74, 211, 203, 0.5)"
    },
    "fillcolor": "rgba(74, 211, 203, 0.25)",
    "mode": "lines",
    "hoverinfo": "none"
  },
  {
    "x": [
      0,
      90,
      180,
      270,
    ],
    "y": [
      709,
      657,
      99,
      113,
    ],
    "type": "scatter",
    "yaxis": "y6",
    "xaxis": "x",
    "name": "Channel Name 7",
    "showlegend": true,
    "visible": true,
    "marker": {
      "color": "rgba(106, 155, 188, 0.5)"
    },
    "line": {
      "width": 2,
      "color": "rgba(106, 155, 188, 0.5)"
    },
    "fillcolor": "rgba(106, 155, 188, 0.25)",
    "mode": "lines",
    "hoverinfo": "none"
  },
  {
    "x": [
      0,
      90,
      180,
      270,
    ],
    "y": [
      203,
      2,
      193,
      826,
    ],
    "type": "scatter",
    "yaxis": "y8",
    "xaxis": "x",
    "name": "Channel Name 8",
    "showlegend": true,
    "visible": true,
    "marker": {
      "color": "rgba(190, 235, 185, 0.5)"
    },
    "line": {
      "width": 2,
      "color": "rgba(190, 235, 185, 0.5)"
    },
    "fillcolor": "rgba(190, 235, 185, 0.25)",
    "mode": "lines",
    "hoverinfo": "none"
  }
];

var layout = {
  "xaxis": {
    "autorange": true,
    "domain": [
      0.05,
      0.95
    ],
    "zeroline": false,
    "tickfont": {
      "color": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)"
    },
    "tickcolor": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)",
    "linecolor": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)",
    "gridcolor": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12)",
    "visible": true,
    "anchor": "y2",
    "title": {
      "text": "X axis label",
      "font": {
        "color": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)"
      }
    },
    "type": "linear"
  },
  "paper_bgcolor": "rgba(46, 46, 46, 1)",
  "plot_bgcolor": "rgba(46, 46, 46, 1)",
  "legend": {
    "font": {
      "color": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)"
    }
  },
  "barmode": "overlay",
  "yaxis": {
    "title": {
      "text": "Channel Name 1 [unit 1]",
      "font": {
        "color": "rgba(76, 198, 233, 1)"
      }
    },
    "showgrid": false,
    "zeroline": false,
    "automargin": true,
    "tickfont": {
      "color": "rgba(76, 198, 233, 1)"
    },
    "tickcolor": "rgba(76, 198, 233, 1)",
    "linecolor": "rgba(76, 198, 233, 1)",
    "side": "left",
    "anchor": "x",
    "showspikes": false,
    "fixedrange": false,
    "domain": [
      0.55,
      1
    ],
    "type": "linear"
  },
  "yaxis3": {
    "title": {
      "text": "Channel Name 2 [unit 2]",
      "font": {
        "color": "rgba(239, 151, 191, 1)"
      }
    },
    "showgrid": false,
    "zeroline": false,
    "automargin": true,
    "tickfont": {
      "color": "rgba(239, 151, 191, 1)"
    },
    "tickcolor": "rgba(239, 151, 191, 1)",
    "linecolor": "rgba(239, 151, 191, 1)",
    "side": "right",
    "anchor": "x",
    "showspikes": false,
    "fixedrange": false,
    "overlaying": "y",
    "domain": [
      0.55,
      1
    ],
    "type": "linear"
  },
  "yaxis5": {
    "title": {
      "text": "Channel Name 3",
      "font": {
        "color": "rgba(245, 150, 50, 1)"
      }
    },
    "showgrid": false,
    "zeroline": false,
    "automargin": true,
    "tickfont": {
      "color": "rgba(245, 150, 50, 1)"
    },
    "tickcolor": "rgba(245, 150, 50, 1)",
    "linecolor": "rgba(245, 150, 50, 1)",
    "side": "left",
    "anchor": "free",
    "showspikes": false,
    "fixedrange": false,
    "overlaying": "y",
    "position": 0,
    "domain": [
      0.55,
      1
    ],
    "type": "linear"
  },
  "yaxis7": {
    "title": {
      "text": "Channel Name 4 [unit 4]",
      "font": {
        "color": "rgba(218, 227, 109, 1)"
      }
    },
    "showgrid": false,
    "zeroline": false,
    "automargin": true,
    "tickfont": {
      "color": "rgba(218, 227, 109, 1)"
    },
    "tickcolor": "rgba(218, 227, 109, 1)",
    "linecolor": "rgba(218, 227, 109, 1)",
    "side": "right",
    "anchor": "free",
    "showspikes": false,
    "fixedrange": false,
    "overlaying": "y",
    "position": 1,
    "domain": [
      0.55,
      1
    ],
    "type": "linear"
  },
  "yaxis2": {
    "title": {
      "text": "Channel Name 5 [unit 5]",
      "font": {
        "color": "rgba(178, 74, 195, 1)"
      }
    },
    "showgrid": false,
    "zeroline": false,
    "automargin": true,
    "tickfont": {
      "color": "rgba(178, 74, 195, 1)"
    },
    "tickcolor": "rgba(178, 74, 195, 1)",
    "linecolor": "rgba(178, 74, 195, 1)",
    "side": "left",
    "anchor": "x",
    "showspikes": false,
    "fixedrange": false,
    "domain": [
      0.05,
      0.5
    ],
    "type": "linear",
    
  },
  "yaxis4": {
    "title": {
      "text": "Channel Name 6",
      "font": {
        "color": "rgba(74, 211, 203, 1)"
      }
    },
    "showgrid": false,
    "zeroline": false,
    "automargin": true,
    "tickfont": {
      "color": "rgba(74, 211, 203, 1)"
    },
    "tickcolor": "rgba(74, 211, 203, 1)",
    "linecolor": "rgba(74, 211, 203, 1)",
    "side": "right",
    "anchor": "x",
    "showspikes": false,
    "fixedrange": false,
    "overlaying": "y2",
    "domain": [
      0.05,
      0.5
    ],
    "type": "linear",
  },
  "yaxis6": {
    "title": {
      "text": "Channel Name 7 [unit 7]",
      "font": {
        "color": "rgba(106, 155, 188, 1)"
      }
    },
    "showgrid": false,
    "zeroline": false,
    "automargin": true,
    "tickfont": {
      "color": "rgba(106, 155, 188, 1)"
    },
    "tickcolor": "rgba(106, 155, 188, 1)",
    "linecolor": "rgba(106, 155, 188, 1)",
    "side": "left",
    "anchor": "free",
    "showspikes": false,
    "fixedrange": false,
    "overlaying": "y2",
    "position": 0,
    "domain": [
      0.05,
      0.5
    ],
    "type": "linear",
  },
  "yaxis8": {
    "title": {
      "text": "Channel Name 8 [unit 8]",
      "font": {
        "color": "rgba(190, 235, 185, 1)"
      }
    },
    "showgrid": false,
    "zeroline": false,
    "automargin": true,
    "tickfont": {
      "color": "rgba(190, 235, 185, 1)"
    },
    "tickcolor": "rgba(190, 235, 185, 1)",
    "linecolor": "rgba(190, 235, 185, 1)",
    "side": "right",
    "anchor": "free",
    "showspikes": false,
    "fixedrange": false,
    "overlaying": "y2",
    "position": 1,
    "domain": [
      0.05,
      0.5
    ],
    "type": "linear"
  },
  "grid": {
    "columns": 1,
    "rows": 2
  },
  "xaxis2": {
    "domain": [
      0.05,
      0.95
    ],
    "showgrid": false,
    "zeroline": false,
    "automargin": true,
    "tickfont": {
      "color": "rgba(74, 211, 203, 1)"
    },
    "gridcolor": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12)",
    "tickcolor": "rgba(74, 211, 203, 1)",
    "linecolor": "rgba(74, 211, 203, 1)",
    "anchor": "free",
    "position": 0,
    "overlaying": "x",
    "scaleanchor": "x",
    "type": "linear",
    "autorange": true
  },
  "showlegend": false
};

Plotly.newPlot("myDiv", data, layout, {
  responsive: true
});
<head>
  <!-- Load plotly.js into the DOM -->
  <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.35.2.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='myDiv'>
    <!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV -->
  </div>
</body>



However, in some other cases it is not generating expected results and I am unable to figure out what is wrong here (seems something with overlaying property of x axis).


var data = [{
    x: [
      0,
      90,
      180,
      270,
    ],
    y: [
      0,
      26,
      408,
      24,
    ],
    type: "scatter",
    yaxis: "y",
    xaxis: "x",
    name: "Channel 1",
    showlegend: true,
    visible: true,
    marker: {
      color: "rgba(76, 198, 233, 0.5)"
    },
    line: {
      width: 2,
      color: "rgba(76, 198, 233, 0.5)"
    },
    fillcolor: "rgba(76, 198, 233, 0.25)",
    mode: "lines",
    hoverinfo: "none"
  },
  {
    x: [
      0,
      90,
      180,
      270,
    ],
    y: [
      518,
      1212,
      696,
      9,
    ],
    type: "scatter",
    yaxis: "y3",
    xaxis: "x",
    name: "Channel 2",
    showlegend: true,
    visible: true,
    marker: {
      color: "rgba(239, 151, 191, 0.5)"
    },
    line: {
      width: 2,
      color: "rgba(239, 151, 191, 0.5)"
    },
    fillcolor: "rgba(239, 151, 191, 0.25)",
    mode: "lines",
    hoverinfo: "none"
  },
  {
    x: [
      0,
      90,
      180,
      270,
    ],
    y: [
      174,
      203,
      38,
      48,
    ],
    type: "scatter",
    yaxis: "y5",
    xaxis: "x",
    name: "Channel 3",
    showlegend: true,
    visible: true,
    marker: {
      color: "rgba(245, 150, 50, 0.5)"
    },
    line: {
      width: 2,
      color: "rgba(245, 150, 50, 0.5)"
    },
    fillcolor: "rgba(245, 150, 50, 0.25)",
    mode: "lines",
    hoverinfo: "none"
  },
  {
    x: [
      0,
      90,
      180,
      270,
    ],
    y: [
      737,
      307,
      0,
      96,
    ],
    type: "scatter",
    yaxis: "y7",
    xaxis: "x",
    name: "Channel 4",
    showlegend: true,
    visible: true,
    marker: {
      color: "rgba(218, 227, 109, 0.5)"
    },
    line: {
      width: 2,
      color: "rgba(218, 227, 109, 0.5)"
    },
    fillcolor: "rgba(218, 227, 109, 0.25)",
    mode: "lines",
    hoverinfo: "none"
  },
  {
    x: [
      0,
      90,
      180,
      270,
    ],
    y: [
      3,
      108,
      314,
      218,
    ],
    type: "scatter",
    yaxis: "y2",
    xaxis: "x2",
    name: "Channel 5",
    showlegend: true,
    visible: true,
    marker: {
      color: "rgba(178, 74, 195, 0.5)"
    },
    line: {
      width: 2,
      color: "rgba(178, 74, 195, 0.5)"
    },
    fillcolor: "rgba(178, 74, 195, 0.25)",
    mode: "lines",
    hoverinfo: "none"
  },
  {
    x: [
      0,
      90,
      180,
      270,
    ],
    y: [
      202,
      0,
      72,
      951,
    ],
    type: "scatter",
    yaxis: "y4",
    xaxis: "x",
    name: "Channel 6",
    showlegend: true,
    visible: true,
    marker: {
      color: "rgba(74, 211, 203, 0.5)"
    },
    line: {
      width: 2,
      color: "rgba(74, 211, 203, 0.5)"
    },
    fillcolor: "rgba(74, 211, 203, 0.25)",
    mode: "lines",
    hoverinfo: "none"
  },
  {
    x: [
      0,
      90,
      180,
      270,
    ],
    y: [
      98,
      303,
      1146,
      914,
    ],
    type: "scatter",
    yaxis: "y6",
    xaxis: "x",
    name: "Channel 7",
    showlegend: true,
    visible: true,
    marker: {
      color: "rgba(106, 155, 188, 0.5)"
    },
    line: {
      width: 2,
      color: "rgba(106, 155, 188, 0.5)"
    },
    fillcolor: "rgba(106, 155, 188, 0.25)",
    mode: "lines",
    hoverinfo: "none"
  },
  {
    x: [
      0,
      90,
      180,
      270,
    ],
    y: [
      976,
      455,
      0,
      440,
    ],
    type: "scatter",
    yaxis: "y8",
    xaxis: "x",
    name: "Channel 8",
    showlegend: true,
    visible: true,
    marker: {
      color: "rgba(190, 235, 185, 0.5)"
    },
    line: {
      width: 2,
      color: "rgba(190, 235, 185, 0.5)"
    },
    fillcolor: "rgba(190, 235, 185, 0.25)",
    mode: "lines",
    hoverinfo: "none"
  }
];

var layout = {
  xaxis: {
    domain: [0.05, 0.95],
    zeroline: false,
    tickfont: {
      color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)"
    },
    tickcolor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)",
    linecolor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)",
    gridcolor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12)",
    visible: true,
    anchor: "y2",
    title: {
      text: "X axis label",
      font: {
        color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)"
      }
    },
    type: "linear"
  },
  paper_bgcolor: "rgba(46, 46, 46, 1)",
  plot_bgcolor: "rgba(46, 46, 46, 1)",
  legend: {
    font: {
      color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)"
    }
  },
  barmode: "overlay",
  yaxis: {
    title: {
      text: "Channel 1 [unit 1]",
      font: {
        color: "rgba(76, 198, 233, 1)"
      }
    },
    showgrid: false,
    zeroline: false,
    automargin: true,
    tickfont: {
      color: "rgba(76, 198, 233, 1)"
    },
    tickcolor: "rgba(76, 198, 233, 1)",
    linecolor: "rgba(76, 198, 233, 1)",
    side: "left",
    anchor: "x",
    showspikes: false,
    fixedrange: false,
    domain: [0.55, 1],
    type: "linear"
  },
  yaxis3: {
    title: {
      text: "Channel 2 [unit 2]",
      font: {
        color: "rgba(239, 151, 191, 1)"
      }
    },
    showgrid: false,
    zeroline: false,
    automargin: true,
    tickfont: {
      color: "rgba(239, 151, 191, 1)"
    },
    tickcolor: "rgba(239, 151, 191, 1)",
    linecolor: "rgba(239, 151, 191, 1)",
    side: "right",
    anchor: "x",
    showspikes: false,
    fixedrange: false,
    overlaying: "y",
    domain: [0.55, 1],
    type: "linear",
  },
  yaxis5: {
    title: {
      text: "Channel 3",
      font: {
        color: "rgba(245, 150, 50, 1)"
      }
    },
    showgrid: false,
    zeroline: false,
    automargin: true,
    tickfont: {
      color: "rgba(245, 150, 50, 1)"
    },
    tickcolor: "rgba(245, 150, 50, 1)",
    linecolor: "rgba(245, 150, 50, 1)",
    side: "left",
    anchor: "free",
    showspikes: false,
    fixedrange: false,
    overlaying: "y",
    position: 0,
    domain: [0.55, 1],
    type: "linear",
  },
  yaxis7: {
    title: {
      text: "Channel 4 [unit 4]",
      font: {
        color: "rgba(218, 227, 109, 1)"
      }
    },
    showgrid: false,
    zeroline: false,
    automargin: true,
    tickfont: {
      color: "rgba(218, 227, 109, 1)"
    },
    tickcolor: "rgba(218, 227, 109, 1)",
    linecolor: "rgba(218, 227, 109, 1)",
    side: "right",
    anchor: "free",
    showspikes: false,
    fixedrange: false,
    overlaying: "y",
    position: 1,
    domain: [0.55, 1],
    type: "linear",        
  },
  yaxis2: {
    title: {
      text: "Channel 5 [unit 5]",
      font: {
        color: "rgba(178, 74, 195, 1)"
      }
    },
    showgrid: false,
    zeroline: false,
    automargin: true,
    tickfont: {
      color: "rgba(178, 74, 195, 1)"
    },
    tickcolor: "rgba(178, 74, 195, 1)",
    linecolor: "rgba(178, 74, 195, 1)",
    side: "left",
    anchor: "x",
    showspikes: false,
    fixedrange: false,
    domain: [0.05, 0.5],
    type: "linear",
  },
  yaxis4: {
    title: {
      text: "Channel 6",
      font: {
        color: "rgba(74, 211, 203, 1)"
      }
    },
    showgrid: false,
    zeroline: false,
    automargin: true,
    tickfont: {
      color: "rgba(74, 211, 203, 1)"
    },
    tickcolor: "rgba(74, 211, 203, 1)",
    linecolor: "rgba(74, 211, 203, 1)",
    side: "right",
    anchor: "x",
    showspikes: false,
    fixedrange: false,
    overlaying: "y2",
    domain: [0.05, 0.5],
    type: "linear",
  },
  yaxis6: {
    title: {
      text: "Channel 7 [unit 7]",
      font: {
        color: "rgba(106, 155, 188, 1)"
      }
    },
    showgrid: false,
    zeroline: false,
    automargin: true,
    tickfont: {
      color: "rgba(106, 155, 188, 1)"
    },
    tickcolor: "rgba(106, 155, 188, 1)",
    linecolor: "rgba(106, 155, 188, 1)",
    side: "left",
    anchor: "free",
    showspikes: false,
    fixedrange: false,
    overlaying: "y2",
    position: 0,
    domain: [0.05, 0.5],
    type: "linear",
  },
  yaxis8: {
    title: {
      text: "Channel 8 [unit 8]",
      font: {
        color: "rgba(190, 235, 185, 1)"
      }
    },
    showgrid: false,
    zeroline: false,
    automargin: true,
    tickfont: {
      color: "rgba(190, 235, 185, 1)"
    },
    tickcolor: "rgba(190, 235, 185, 1)",
    linecolor: "rgba(190, 235, 185, 1)",
    side: "right",
    anchor: "free",
    showspikes: false,
    fixedrange: false,
    overlaying: "y2",
    position: 1,
    domain: [0.05, 0.5],
    type: "linear"
  },
  grid: {
    columns: 1,
    rows: 2
  },
  xaxis2: {
    showgrid: false,
    zeroline: false,
    automargin: true,
    tickfont: {
      color: "rgba(178, 74, 195, 1)"
    },
    gridcolor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12)",
    tickcolor: "rgba(178, 74, 195, 1)",
    linecolor: "rgba(178, 74, 195, 1)",
    anchor: "free",
    position: 0,
    scaleanchor: "x",
    type: "linear",
    domain: [0.05, 0.95],
    overlaying: 'x'
  },
  showlegend: false
};

Plotly.newPlot("myDiv", data, layout, {
  responsive: true
});
<head>
  <!-- Load plotly.js into the DOM -->
  <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.35.2.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='myDiv'>
    <!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV -->
  </div>
</body>




I just noted, it works if I update yaxis6.overlaying = yaxis2.overlaying = yaxis8.overlaying = 'y4' and remove yaxis4.overlaying, but I still think old config should have worked too.

Also, posted it on plotly as an issue, https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/7300
